# Selenium ChromeDriver fails to launch browser executable with chromedriver v74.0.3729.6

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I'm trying to use Selenium with an application with an embedded browser (ZFBrowser) which uses Chromium v74.0.3729.157. I'm using the following code to attempt to start the session:

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.BinaryLocation = "<path_to_executable_with_embedded_browser>";
_driver = new ChromeDriver("<path_to_chromedriver_v74.0.3729.6", opt);
```

This just silently fails however without opening the application (or any other application I tested) or giving an error. The only error I was able to obtain was with the following code:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;      
object title = js.ExecuteScript("return document.title");

if (title is string)
    Console.WriteLine((string)title);
if (title is Dictionary<string, object>)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> err = (Dictionary<string, object>)title;

    foreach (var kvp in err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: " + kvp.Key);
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + (string)kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

which produced the following output:

> ```
>     Key: message
>     Value: invalid session id
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19043 x86_64)
> ```

If I swap out chromedriver v74 with chromedriver v94, it launches the application with no issues, though unsurprisingly fails to connect.

How can I get chromedriver v74 to launch the application?

I'm using:
Windows 10, C# (.NET 5.0), Selenium.WebDriver 4.0.0-rc1

Comment: I believe its compatibility issue. Chrome driver and browser versions should be in sync if you want to test with `74` version you need to degrade your browser version.

Comment: To be clear, you are referring to my installed chrome version? The browser embedded within the application is chromium v74, however my installed chrome version on my computer is v94. I had assumed that setting ChromeOptions.BinaryLocation to a new location would avoid Selenium interacting with my installed browser.